# PHP mySQL, inserting content into two tables

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to insert into two database tables with one try!

```
$query = "INSERT INTO category 
        (base_img) VALUES ('$imgsrc')";

$insert_row = $db->insert($query);

//Getting last ID
$catID = mysql_insert_id();

$query = "INSERT INTO cat_lng
        (locate, foreign_id, name, body) VALUES
        ('lv', '$catID', '$name_lv', '$text_lv'),
        ('ru', '$catID', '$name_ru', '$text_ru'),
        ('en', '$catID', '$name_en', '$text_en')";

$insert_row = $db->insert($query);
```

My insert function:

```
public function insert($query){
        $insert_row = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);

        //Validate Insert
        if($insert_row){
            header("Location: index.php?msg=".urlencode('Record Added'));
            exit();
        } else {
            die('Error : ('. $this->link->errno .') '. $this->link->error);
        }
   }
```

Code inserts into category, but stops after that! Cant figure out why..?
They work seperatly but cant get them working together!

Comment: Does it throw an error?

Comment: No. It jumps to the index page as everything would be fine

Comment: Ok! I found an error. "Validate insert" takes me to the index.php after first instert. deleted that and now it works. But mysql_insert_id(); is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello: The exit() functions terminates the execution of the script.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

You might change:

```
exit()
```

to

```
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of $query as $query1 and $insert_row as $insert_row1 which will insert $query1 or any other name you like to use than use the if as follow:

```
if($insertrow && $insertrow1)
 {
        //bunch of code here
 }
```

And also you can use mysqli_muti_query function for one name.